# How to download a filled in form in PDF format using javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page with a form ,with few input fields, check box,radio buttons.
User can fill up the forms.

Is there any way , the user will be able to download the form (with the filled in data) in pdf format ?

1 more question, Any way to save the filled in form in html format or image format (of course File-> save of browser and screenshot are there) using java script code or html code , on a button click ?

I have tried http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/ , didnot able to get through it.

Thanks

[Adding a few more points]
if generating a pdf file using JS/HTML is not possible then ....
A bit more into it

Currently I am creating a server using C# application and when user requests a html page , I am sending the same to user.
that html page contains a form , which is needed to be filled
and I want the user to save the filled form in pdf format.
For now , I am able to process the static html form -> convert to pdf and provide the download to user ,

But can't get a way to enable the user to save the filled in form.
When the user presses the submit button , I can get all the filled in data using httpResponce object(GET/Post Method)!!  , is there a way I can generate a pdf file using this httpResponce object parameters?
Or any way I can send the current html page content (e.g. getting all the contents in a div using jquery/javascript) and send it back, when user presses the submit button, in that way I can generate the pdf file at server side and provide a download - PDF format

Please ask , if I am not able to describe my question !!

Answer (score 2):

> jsPDF is an open-source library written by our lead developer, James,
>   for generating PDF documents using nothing but Javascript. You can use
>   it in a Firefox extension, in Server Side Javascript and with Data
>   URIs in some browsers. http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf

Using only javascript to generate the PDF is not possible at this time. Using server-side scripting, it is possible to send the data to a server and let the server generate the PDF which is then sent to the user.

**(Update)**: Using PHP, you can generate PDFs in the server-side using [dompdf - HTML to pdf converter](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/). Here is a demo: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/docs_0-6-0/demo.php

In Google Chrome, there is a "Print to PDF" option. If you don't want to do any programming on the server side, you can just ask your users to access the page using Google Chrome. After filling out the form, they [print the page as PDF](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1379552).

Comment: As I have mentioned in the comment, I have tried to use jspdf, cant get a easy way !!

And thanks a lot about the google chrome option , that helps a lot

Still , if any one can provide any other way to generate pdfs , will be a great help ..

Thanks again rationalboss

Comment: I appreciate your effort and answer .

Actually , I am using C# as my server , and pure html/JS/Lquery in the html page .

So using PHP is not an option for me :(

Comment: Then maybe you can make C# send the HTML data to http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/docs_0-6-0/demo.php or another server running DOMPDF that will output you the PDF form. That is if you don't want the print the page as PDF option in Chrome. :)

Comment: Got it , Is there any option , like While when I get the User submitted data , to generate the pdf format of the whole html page ?, in server side Code ?

Comment: Yes, just send the POST data in the demo link I gave above. Your input is HTML and its output is PDF.

Comment: if I send the post data to the above link it will obviously generate pdf file of the data only, what abt the whole html form design

and any way to send the data to this page ?